# Silverlight / Expression: XAML build error

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

I'm getting the following errors:

> obj\Debug\StoryList.g.cs(40,22): error
> CS0102: The type
> 'Newsreader.StoryList'
> already contains a definition for
> '_contentLoaded'
>
> obj\Debug\StoryList.g.cs(46,21): error
> CS0111: Type
> 'Newsreader.StoryList'
> already defines a member called
> 'InitializeComponent' with the same
> parameter types

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyLayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <ScrollViewer d:LayoutOverrides="Height" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="424">
        <StackPanel Height="865">
            <local:StoryControl Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <ic:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/StoryPage.xaml"/>
                    </Custom:EventTrigger>
                </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
            </local:StoryControl>
            <local:StoryControl Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <ic:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/StoryPage.xaml"/>
                    </Custom:EventTrigger>
                </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
            </local:StoryControl>
            <local:StoryControl Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <ic:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/StoryPage.xaml"/>
                    </Custom:EventTrigger>
                </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
            </local:StoryControl>
            <local:StoryControl Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

What could I be doing wrong here? I was copying/pasting to create new controls. Could that possibly have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

do you happen to have a '_contentLoaded' and 'InitializeComponent' defined elsewhere in Newsreader.StoryList (e.g. in StoryList.cs)?

If you open StoryList.g.cs and look at the generated code, you might be able to see the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue duplicating a ResourceDictionary from someone else's code.

In my case I discovered that in the source ResourceDictionary someone had defined an x:Class name.  The compiler was trying to mash the source and duplicate together in the same object, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below could be one of the reason.
When you copy existing control to create new one, you seems forgot to update x:Class.
For example see below two controls pointing to same partial class.
 
//StoryList.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Newsreader.StoryList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             . . . 
             Title=" StoryList"
             Height="194" Width="450">

//AnotherFile.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Newsreader.StoryList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             . . . 
             Title="AnotherFile"
             Height="120" Width="320">

Change in AnotherFile.xaml  as x:Class="Newsreader.AnotherFile" 
You should be fine.
```